# Использование констант define() для подключения к БД через pdo

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Уместно ли подключение к БД с использованием констант? Константы определены, но в коде:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=HOST; dbname=DB;charset=utf8", "USER", "PASS");
```

выдаёт ошибку

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown
> MySQL server host 'HOST' (1)

Comment: @Torawhite, ну так вы не указали адрес сервера, к которому подключаетесь. Для большинства случаев должно быть

    mysql:host=localhost

Comment: @Dazar, отличный ответ, принимая во внимание то, что я прямо сейчас вижу:

> mysql:host=HOST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php не умеет интерполировать строки константами. Они просто физически не отличаются от слов, поэтому непонятно было бы, что делать ос словами, чье имя совпадает с именем константы.

```
 $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=utf8', HOST, DB);
 $pdo = new PDO($dsn, USER, PASS);
```

Теперь у меня один вопрос: зачем вы вообще это в константы сохраняете?

Comment: @Etki в обучающем видео был такой пример. Лучше их просто занести в переменные? Я так понимаю, автор урока работает с константами, как лучше подходящими, по той простой причине, что они постоянные, наверное. Но у него соединение идёт через mysql_connect. А вообще я формирую config.php

Comment: @Torawhite, ну их желательно прокинуть из конфига в создание PDO без следов в глобальной области видимости.

Comment: @Etki, что-то это для меня пока тёмный лес. Если есть возможность, объясните более простым языком, для чайника, так сказать.

Comment: @Torawhite в текущем варианте вы наследите абсолютно ненужными константами, которые будут видны для всех, и какая-нибудь упоротая библиотека, которая тоже использует USER, не сможет его проставить и упадет. Константами же должны быть действительно неизменяемые значения - версия программы, символ конца строки, при этом лежать они должны в классах, чтобы опять же не мусорить в общей области видимости.

Answer (score 0):

Лови:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.'; dbname='.DB.';charset=utf8', USER, PASS);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?